# Identificar se conjunto de coordenadas que está dentro de um raio na base ORACLE

Tags: oracle, script

Ola pessoal eu tenho um script aqui em MYsql, porem eu preciso aplica-lo em uma base de dados o Oracle,

```
SELECT *,(RAIO_TERRESTRE * 
    acos(
     cos(radians(PARAMETRO_LATITUDE)) * 
     cos(radians(COLUNA_LATITUDE)) * 
     cos(radians(PARAMETRO_LONGITUDE) - radians(COLUNA_LONGITUDE)) + 
     sin(radians(PARAMETRO_LATITUDE)) * 
     sin(radians(COLUNA_LATITUDE))
  )) AS CAMPOLATITUDE
FROM TABELA HAVING CAMPOLATITUDE <= KM
```

---

EXEMPLO:

```
SELECT *, (6371 *
        acos(
            cos(radians(-19.83996)) *
            cos(radians(lat)) *
            cos(radians(-43.94910) - radians(lng)) +
            sin(radians(-19.83996)) *
            sin(radians(lat))
        )) AS distance
FROM tabela HAVING distance <= 5
```

o que este script faz e o seguinte:

Eu tenho uma base de dados em ORACLE com as coordenadas de latitude (lat) e longitude (lng) e estou  passando o um ponto de referência (no exemplo os valores -19.83996 e 43.94910).Com isso obtenho todos os locais que estão à uma distância de 5 Km do ponto de referência.
Porem este script esta em Mysql e tentei aplica-lo no Oracle mas apresenta erros.

Comment: "mas apresenta erros" , erro de que , síntaxe , cálculo , etc , o 2º script é do Oracle ?

Comment: já pesquisou se as functions são iguais no oracle? `cos`, `sin`, `radians`?

Comment: Não , este script e do Mysql e preciso aplica-lo no Oracle.

Comment: @Motta quando rodo o script no oracle apresenta este erro 
"ORA-00904: "RADIANS": identificador inválido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erro na linha: 6 Coluna: 17"

Comment: https://www.databasedevelop.com/article/10310157/RADIANS+and+DEGREES    https://matika.com.br/radianos/conversao-de-radianos-para-graus

Comment: Parece que esta function foi descontinuada.

Comment: @MOTTA mas e um operador matemático, eles não podem descontinuar assim, podem ter mudado a forma de aplicação, mas descontinuar eu duvido

Comment: Digo isto pois achei uma doc desta function < https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rreffuncradians.html > , realmente não pesquisei mas a fundo , mas creio que a solução neste caso é simples , criar uma user function.

Comment: Pois e, ja tentei de tudo, a solução mais rápida que eu encontrei foi gerar um arquivo .txt com os dados das coordenadas e importa-lo em uma base de dados do Mysql eu realmente não queria fazer isso devido tomar muito tempo ,eu queria que o sistema ja me desse os dados direto do bando do Oracle. mas essa foi a forma mais rápida que encontrei, espero algum dia resolver este script.